# Angular - Common ngOnInit

Tags: angular, boilerplate, ngoninit

If I have in every component

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('hello world');
}
```

How do I avoid writing that code in each component?
Can I write some common code that will trigger onInit for each component, maybe in their module? Or in their shared service they all use, for example?

I have the same question about **NavigationStart** and **NavigationEnd**.

Thx

Comment: you can create a custom decorator, https://netbasal.com/inspiration-for-custom-decorators-in-angular-95aeb87f072c

Comment: Please provide more information as to what your actual goal is.

Comment: What does it matter? The goal is to avoid boilerplate. The goal is to notify user the component is initialized. Whatever. However, Dmitry Sobolevsky gave excellent answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is by extending from the base component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'base-component',
    template: '',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

 ngOnInit (): void {
  console.log('hello world');
 }
}
```

and use `extends BaseComponent` in your child components, for example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: '',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent {
  // your logic
}
```

**Another way**: using service with a local provider for each component:

```
@Injectable()
export class ActionService {
 constructor(){
   console.log('hello world');
 }
}
```

and inject it (`providers: [ActionService]`) to your component which has to has this logic, each component will have a separate instance of this service:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main-page',
    templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main-page.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    providers: [ActionService]
})
export class MainPageComponent {}
```

***as for me: the first solution much better than providing service each time, but it's up to you :)***

Comment: Excellent answer, clear and understandable. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you create a utility class with static methods.

Let's say you want to print hello world every time a component is initialized:

utility.ts:

```
class Utility {
    static printHelloWorld() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
}
```

In component.ts:

First, import the utility class as:

```
import Utility from './path/to/utility/class';
```

Then, in the ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit() {
   Utility.printHelloWorld();
}
```

Comment: This is just replacing one line in each component with another. Doesn't solve anything.